# PHP - Memory leak - Object doesn't unset from ram and gc_collect_cycles do nothing

Tags: php, memory-management, memory-leaks

I write a sample code to understand how mange memory using in long script on php.

But I just can't realize this behavior

This code should clean memory from unused object, but it do almost nothing

```
<?php

memory_using('start');

class a
{
    public $v = [];

    public function init()
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= 1000000; $i++)
        {
            $this->v[$i] = [rand(10000, 99999), rand(10000, 99999), rand(10000, 99999)];
        }
    }
}


$a = new a;

memory_using('before init');
$a->init();
memory_using('after init');

unset($a);
memory_using('after unset a');

gc_collect_cycles();
memory_using('after gc_collect_cycles');

xdebug_debug_zval('a');


function memory_using($where = null)
{
    echo(sprintf("Memory using: %4s %s\n", convertToReadableSize(memory_get_usage(true)), $where));

}

function convertToReadableSize($size)
{
    $base = log($size) / log(1024);
    $suffix = array("B", "KB", "MB", "GB", "TB");
    $f_base = floor($base);
    return round(pow(1024, $base - floor($base)), 1) . $suffix[$f_base];
}
```

This is result of code:

```
Memory using:    2MB start
Memory using:    2MB before init
Memory using:  394MB after init
Memory using:  360MB after unset a
Memory using:  360MB after gc_collect_cycles
a: no such symbol
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for memory_get_usage states the following for the parameter:
"Set this to true to get total memory allocated from system, **including unused pages**."

The memory you are seeing contains unused memory that was not yet claimed by another application (since you are collecting the memory dump right away). If you add a sleep command after the gc_collect_cycles, you will see that the numbers will drop.